# Using Gulp to build csproj on .less change

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, gulp

I am currently trying to come up with a gulp task that will build the entire .csproj file associated with a particular .less file whenever that .less file changes.

I already have a working task that will do just that, however the restriction I am facing is that the .less file must be in *a specific place* relative to the .csproj file. If the .less file is one level deeper/higher in the directory, the method I am using to build the .csproj file wont be able to find the correct .csproj file to build.

My current task is based heavily off of one of the tasks found in Kamsar's Habitat repo for Sitecore: https://github.com/kamsar/Habitat

It is as follows:

```
gulp.task("Auto-Publish-Less",
function() {
    var root = "./src";
    var roots = [root + "/**/resources/styles", "!" + root + "/**/obj/**/resources/styles"];
    var files = "/**/*.less";
    gulp.src(roots, { base: root })
        .pipe(
            foreach(function (stream, rootFolder) {
                console.log(rootFolder);
                gulp.watch(rootFolder.path + files,
                    function(event) {
                        if (event.type === "changed") {
                            var dest = config.websiteRoot;
                            console.log("Build project associated with this file: " + event.path);
                            return gulp.src([event.path + "/../../../*.csproj"]).pipe(publishStream(stream,dest));
                        }
                    });
                return stream;
            }));
});
```

This works great so long as the .csproj file is 3 levels higher than the .less file. I could also add more wildcards for 2 levels higher, 1 level higher, etc. However, I was looking to see if there was a way in `gulp.src` to "find" the first matching file, moving up the directory structure, and then stopping once the first match is found. Is there a way to do this in gulp and/or plain-old js?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this package:

Finds the first parent directory that contains a given file or directory:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-parent-dir